# NodeJS script not responding until browser refreshed twice

Tags: javascript, node.js, curl, mariadb

I have the following script that takes URL as argument and retrieves data from MariaDB and displays it.

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var Client = require('mariasql');
var http = require("http");
var url = require("url");
var output;

var c = new Client({
    host: '127.0.0.1',
    user: 'root',
    db: 'MyDB'
});

http.createServer(function(request, response) 
{
    var parsed = url.parse(request.url);
    response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
    if(String(parsed.href) == "/")
    {
        c.query('SELECT * FROM table',
                null,
                //{ useArray: true },
                function(err, rows)
                {
                    if(err)
                    {
                        output = "Incorrect Argument";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        output = rows;
                    }
                }
        );
        c.end();
    }
    response.end(output);                  
}).listen(3000);
```

Now when I run the script the output displayed on the browser is correct but it only appears when I refresh the browser twice. 
I am really very new to NodeJS and I don't know what the issue is, and where exactly I am going wrong.

Comment: Don't you think aforementioned error messages would help us? ;)

Comment: Alright so I figured out CURL part where it doesn't take "&" in URL. 
What I have not been able to figure out is the browser refresh part yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Node/javascript callback functions may be called on a different time. For example, in your code the callback for the query in returned after you end the response - you should end the response in the callback block, as following:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var Client = require('mariasql');
var http = require("http");
var url = require("url");
var output;

var c = new Client({
   host: '127.0.0.1',
   user: 'root',
   db: 'MyDB'
});

http.createServer(function(request, response) {

    var parsed = url.parse(request.url);
    response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
    if(parsed.href == "/") {
      c.query('SELECT * FROM table',
        null,
        //{ useArray: true },
        function(err, rows)
        {
            if(err)
            {
                response.statusCode = 404;
                response.end();
            }
            else
            {
                output = rows;
                response.end(output);
            }

        });
}}).listen(3000);
```

Answer (score 1):

`c.query` is an async function, so put the output in the callback:

```
http.createServer(function(request, response) {
var parsed = url.parse(request.url);
response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
if(String(parsed.href) == "/") {
  c.query('SELECT * FROM table', null, function(err, rows){
      if (err) {
          output = "Incorrect Argument";
      } else {
          output = rows;
      }
      response.end(output);
  });
  c.end();
}    
}).listen(3000);
```

In addition you need to transform the rows into a valid output format. Do you really want to send them as `text/plain`?